# clone doctrine ArrayCollection without reference

Tags: symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

When I do

```
$originalTags = $task->getTags();
$task->removeTag($tag1);
```

then `$tag1` is also removed in `$originalTags`. So the assignment of ArrayCollections is made by reference, how can I clone it to a new ArrayCollection?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: Is $task a doctrine entity?

Comment: @drkey cool, very easy, you can post this as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use native PHP `clone` for [object cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

```
$originalTags = $task->getTags();
$task2 = clone $task;
$task2->removeTag($tag1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the solution myself, but I don't know if this may result in any problems because I could lose data:

```
$originalTags = new ArrayCollection( $task->getTags()->toArray() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than handling this problem individually every time you need getTags(), return a clone from getTags rather than the reference.

```
public function getTags(){
     return new ArrayCollection($this->tags->toArray());
}
```

or if you need to preserve the functionality of getTags passing by reference, create a new function getClonedTags or pass a variable to the get function which will optionally return cloned tags.

```
public function getTags($cloned = false){
    if($cloned){
        return new ArrayCollection($this->tags->toArray());
    }

    return clone $this->tags;
}
```